# Bulma CSS - Button in Input field

Tags: html, css, bulma

Im using Bulma Framework, how move Button to the same line with input field?, it looks input field is full width

My code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="field">
  <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
    <input type="text" class="input is-info is-large" placeholder="Input number in seconds">
    <span class="icon is-medium is-left">
      <i class="fa fa-futbol-o"></i>
    </span>
  </div>      
</div>
<a class="button is-info">GO</a>
```

Result [Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYh0t.png)

Answer (score 11):

http://bulma.io/documentation/form/general/#form-addons

If you want the button on the right but not inside the input,
you can use `has-addons` class to "merge" controls (the input and the button here) like this :

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.5.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="field has-addons">
    <div class="control has-icons-left">
      <input type="text" class="input is-info is-large" placeholder="Input number in seconds">
      <span class="icon is-medium is-left">
        <i class="fa fa-futbol-o"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="control">
        <a class="button is-info is-large">GO</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to have a search input that takes 100% of the width with a button at the right without any space (basically, answer from user404 and Sébastien mixed together)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="field has-addons">
    <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right is-expanded">
        <input type="text" class="input is-info is-large" placeholder="Enter words to search">
        <span class="icon is-medium is-left">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <p class="control">
        <a class="button is-info is-large">SEARCH</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://bulma.io/documentation/form/general/#form-addons

Or you just have to group the filed and the button adding "is-grouped" class in the "field" element.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <div class="field is-grouped">
            <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right is-expanded">
                <input type="text" class="input is-info is-large" placeholder="Input number in seconds">
                <span class="icon is-medium is-left">
                  <i class="fa fa-futbol-o"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
            <p class="control">
                <a class="button is-info is-large">GO</a>
            </p>
        </div>
```